# Using HAVING with GROUPING SETS

Tags: sql, sql-server

My sql string as below

```
SELECT Country, City, COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM   CountriesAndCities
GROUP  BY GROUPING SETS ( ( Country, City ), ( Country) )     
ORDER  BY Country, City
```

I am getting results as below

```
Country     City        CountryCount
----------  ----------  ------------
France      NULL        4 
France      Paris       4           
Spain       NULL        6 
Spain       Barcelona   3           
Spain       Madrid      3
```

If country has got only one city record, can I get results as below with using HAVING

```
Country     City        CountryCount
----------  ----------  ------------
France      Paris       4           
Spain       NULL        6 
Spain       Barcelona   3           
Spain       Madrid      3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT Country, City, COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM   CountriesAndCities
GROUP  BY GROUPING SETS ( ( Country, City ), ( Country) )
HAVING GROUPING(City) = 0
    OR COUNT(DISTINCT City) > 1
ORDER  BY Country, City
```

- `GROUPING(City) = 0` if `City` one of the fields currently being grouped by.
- Conversely, when `GROUPING(City) = 1` then `City` is reported as `NULL`.

This means that we always include the rows where the `City` is mentioned (not `NULL`).

For the other rows, where `GROUPING(City) = 1` aka `City IS NULL`, then we only include the row if more than one `City` has been aggregated in to the result.

Comment: Thank you very much but with this query only returns COUNTRY rows with NULL values

Comment: Sorry, I got it backwards ;)   I've updated it now.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178544.aspx